# Interface value is always null

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface, android-recyclerview

I am using custom recycler view  and in adapter class i have implemented interface which is always null on button click. Here is my adapter class.

```
public class FeedListAdapter extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<AddtoCartHolder> {

 private OnFeedItemClickListener onFeedItemClickListener;
 public FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<CartItem> feedItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.feedItems = feedItems;
    this.filteredfeedItems = feedItems;

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
}

 public void setOnFeedItemClickListener(OnFeedItemClickListener onFeedItemClickListener) {
        this.onFeedItemClickListener = onFeedItemClickListener;
    }

@Override
public AddtoCartHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.feed_item, parent, false);
    AddtoCartHolder viewHolder = new AddtoCartHolder(v);
     setupClickableViews(v, viewHolder);
    return viewHolder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final AddtoCartHolder holder, int position) {

    CartItem item = (CartItem) filteredfeedItems.get(position);
    holder.price.setText((String.valueOf(item.getProductName()) + ""));
    holder.location.setText((String.valueOf(item.getQuantity())) + "");


}

private void setupClickableViews(final View view, final AddtoCartHolder cellFeedViewHolder) {
     cellFeedViewHolder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(onFeedItemClickListener !=null){
                onFeedItemClickListener.onAddClick(v, cellFeedViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Data is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
}

 public interface OnFeedItemClickListener {
        void onAddClick(View v, int position);

    }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return filteredfeedItems.size();
}
```

I am always getting null whenever clicking on button really down know why it is coming null...

Here is my fragment class which have implemented interface.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements FeedListAdapter.OnFeedItemClickListener{

// the method
@Override
public void onAddClick(View v, int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Snackbar.make(clContent, "Product removed from cart!",
            Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Where abouts do you call `setOnFeedItemClickListener`? You need to call it otherwise your listener is always going be null.

Comment: Sir would you suggest me where should i add this code..

Comment: Sure let me write up an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be instantiating a FeedListAdapter in your fragment correct buddy ???

Like using statement :

```
FeedListAdapter adapter = new FeedListAdapter(this.getActivity(),your_array_list)
```

After instantiating your adapter just call your adapter's setOnFeedItemClickListener with `'this'` as argument :) That's all :)

```
adapter.setOnFeedItemClickListener(this)
```

Hope my answer helped you :) Happy coding buddy :)

Comment: @NiteshKumar : Am glad you solved it buddy :) Happy coding :)

Comment: Hi bro can you tell me how can i set text to adapter's textview from activity ?

Comment: You mean setting text to cell in listView right buddy ??? :) Adapter does not have a view of itself bro :) Its just a data source for your listView :) it provides the data to your listview and returns the view for each cell :)

Comment: Ok so it possible to do so.?

Comment: Why will you want to update or set the text of cell from Activity ??? Does not make much sense and a very bad design as well buddy :) rather what you can do is to modify the array list of adapter and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() on it buddy :) Will it not solve your purpose :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110105/discussion-between-nitesh-kumar-and-sandeep-bhandari).

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of things your aren't setting your listener. Thus, `onFeedItemClickListener` is always `null`.
Also `MyFragment` isn't actually doing anything, you haven't inflated a view, overridden `onCreateView(...)`, etc.

There's a few things that you could definitely change to improve your implementation. But to get your listener working:

1. Just get rid of `MyFragment` you don't appear to be using it properly.
2. Move your `implements FeedListAdapter.OnFeedItemClickListener` to your `Activity`. i.e. Make your Activity implement your `OnFeedItemClickListener` interface rather than `MyFragment` (which doesn't appear to be doing anything).
3. Make `FeedListAdapter` set the listener in its constructor:

   ```
   public FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<CartItem> feedItems)
   {
       this.activity = activity;
       // Assume we the activity implements OnFeedItemClickListener
       setOnFeedItemClickListener((OnFeedItemClickListener)activity);
       this.feedItems = feedItems;
       this.filteredfeedItems = feedItems;
       inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
   }
   ```

Please keep in mind that this is a pretty bad implementation and you can definitely improve on it but for the purpose of the question, it's sufficient.

Comment: yeah it helped.. Thanks